# Eclipse Remote Application Platform export resource folder into WAR

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently writing a RAP application and would like to export a folder named "repository" containing several files along with the WAR file created by the WAR Product Configuration file. However, the resource folder is never exported into the WAR. I tried setting several BuildPaths in the the Eclipse project, the Manifest.MF and plugin.xml file. None of that worked.

Also, I also still don't know how to get a path to a contained file/folder within the resource folder on disc. I am for example trying to load a Axis2 Repository from that resource folder and my code for that is the following:

```
context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("/repository/", "/repository/conf/axis2.xml");
```

yet this always throws the error that the repository could not be found in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use WAR Product Tooling plugin to create the .war file, and make sure the repository folder is put into the same project.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Fadvanced%2Fdeployment.html